# passing data to netcat

Tags: command-line, netcat

I'm able to execute the following command with desired output.

> echo -n "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc google.com 80

Why can't I achieve the same result by first connecting via nc,

```
nc google.com 80
```

and then entering "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" in console?

How do the two scenarios differ?

Comment: Both ways works the same way for me (using Mac OS)

Comment: @AleSequeira that was probably because you don't have anything running on port 11300. I updated the question to make it simpler. Do you still get the same output?

Comment: I've tried using this server: `nc -l localhost 11300`, it gave me the same results.

Comment: Aren't you missing an `-e` for the first one?

Comment: For me, the `-C` parameter was missing. This forces the usage of CRLF instead of LF (I am using Windows).